# How does a router send different data to different devices simultaneously?

Tags: wifi, router

How does a WiFi router send different data to different devices at the same time? Since all devices connected to it pick up the same signal being emanated by the router, how do they get the data meant for them?

Does the router do something like send addressed data packets and each device filters out the packets meant for them? Or is the router able to send different info/EM waves to different devices simultaneously?

I've googled this a bunch but haven't been able to find any clear answers. Thanks.

Comment: [802.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Layer_2_%E2%80%93_Datagrams) is the relevant standard.

Comment: This isn't just how WiFi works, this is how the whole Internet works. There isn't a special cable at Google with your name on it - your Google data gets mixed up with everyone else's Google data.

Comment: new tech to consider: beam forming, which makes mimo look simple.

Comment: @user253751 wired networks are different and data is actively routed to the recipient.

Comment: @dandavis AFAIK beam forming is basically just MIMO?

Comment: @user253751 no, it's more than that. it uses specific antenna in specific manners (based on ultra-precise timing) to "point" a signal at a single device in order to maximize bandwidth.

Comment: @dandavis isn't that also what MIMO does?

Comment: @user253751. Like I said "it's more than that". Forming builds on top of MIMO. wiki it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the router do something like send addressed data packets and each device filters out the packets meant for them?

Yes - this is what the MAC address is for.

(There is some complexity with encryption, but in practice it's possible to decrypt packets sent to other devices.)

> Or is the router able to send different info/EM waves to different devices simultaneously?

Yes - this is called [MIMO](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005714/network-and-i-o/wireless.html).

MIMO is an extremely complicated system, but it relies on the way interference and reflected signals interact. All the signals go everywhere, but at the target device the signal is strongest.

Comment: MIMO is optional, of course. Normally, the router just sends things one at a time.

Comment: Do cell towers use MIMO as well?

Comment: @PeterKapteyn certainly in 4G: https://web.stanford.edu/~apaulraj/workshop70/pdf/MIMO_Cellular_Gorokhov.pdf (fairly unreadable paper but confirms the basic fact)